# Azure Service Fabric Template - Which one to choose

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I am creating a service fabric application. I saw in the Microsoft documentation that, based on how we store the data we can choose between stateless and sate full template.

But under .net core 2.0 itself, it has "stateless" and "stateless Asp.net core". What is the difference between these two.

[image]

My requirement is to migrate a existing web api which is stateless. As per the microservice architecture, I have selected a Stateless Asp.Net core template as the front facing api and I am not able to decide the template for Web api.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> it has "stateless" and "stateless Asp.net core". What is the
>   difference between these two.

`Stateless Service` is a simple template to build a basic [reliable services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction).

`Stateless ASP.NET Core` is a more complete template to build a reliable service **that uses ASP.NET Core**. It is a great starting point for any website or web API.

> My requirement is to migrate a existing web api which is stateless. As
>   per the microservice architecture, I have selected a Stateless Asp.Net
>   core template as the front facing api and I am not able to decide the
>   template for Web api.

Do chose Stateless ASP.NET Core because you will host a web API.